# AudioRecord start() error on Android when activity is refreshed.

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-8.0-oreo, voip-android

During a voip call when app goes to background or when callInProgressActivity is refreshed , the voice automatically passes from the microphone to the speakers.
I received error status -38 on AudioRecord but only using Api level 27 on google pixel phone. It is as if the activity tries to use the microphone again and fails and then switch to the speakers. Thanks in advance!

```
E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
02-09 11:42:01.918 2589-10619/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close  SR : 16000 CC : 16 SO : 1999
02-09 11:42:01.918 2589-9790/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
02-09 11:42:01.919 2589-9790/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
02-09 11:42:01.919 2589-2948/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
02-09 11:42:01.919 2589-9790/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.k.a.a(SourceFile:27)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.k.b.run(Unknown Source:14)
                                                     at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.a.b(SourceFile:32)
                                                     at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.c.call(Unknown Source:4)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.h.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:4)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:4)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.l.run(SourceFile:6)
                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393237 | Error code: 393222 | couldn't start recording, state is:1
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.ru(SourceFile:165)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:109)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ax.read(SourceFile:2)
                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ar.run(SourceFile:17)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.aq.run(SourceFile:2)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.h.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:4) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:4) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.l.run(SourceFile:6) 
                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393222 | couldn't start recording, state is:1
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.biZ(SourceFile:48)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.read(SourceFile:61)
                                                     at com.google.common.l.l.a(SourceFile:47)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.ru(SourceFile:162)
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:109) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ax.read(SourceFile:2) 
                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ar.run(SourceFile:17) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.aq.run(SourceFile:2) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.h.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:4) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:4) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.l.run(SourceFile:6) 
02-09 11:42:01.919 2589-9790/? I/AudioController: internalShutdown
```

Comment: Put your code Please so we can assist you

Comment: Thanks ! I can't put the code here sorry. But i tested the application in several devices and work well. I think the problem  is oreo related.